# SFDX command to find the latest package version

Tags: salesforcedx

To facilitate deploying packages, it is helpful to quickly identify what the latest package version instead of manually finding the latest package version id.

I cannot find a [sfdx command to install](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_install_pkg_cli.htm) the latest package version when given a parameter, such as the package name.

For example, it would be great to do something like this:

> sfdx force:package:version:list -p "Package A" -latest

Is there a helpful sfdx command to do this? It's possible to do this via a bash script etc, but would be nicer if there was a sfdx way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spent several hours searching and looks like script is the only solution.

Raised enhancement request https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/issues/165

For now just using bash to resolve latest version(based on creation date):

```
latestVersion=$(sfdx force:package:version:list -p '%sf.pkg.name%' -o CreatedDate --concise | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}')
```

Most likely, everyone has a similar script in their CI/CD setup.

Comment: BTW, you can use `-o "CreatedDate DESC"` to reverse the order (and use "head" instead of "tail").

Answer (score 5):

You can use the tooling API (`sfdx force:data:soql:query`) to simply query for package versions:

```sql
SELECT Id,Package2Id,SubscriberPackageVersionId,Description,IsDeprecated,IsPasswordProtected,IsReleased FROM Package2Version ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

This query will return the latest package version, with `SubscriberPackageVersionId` beeing the `04t` Id that you can use to install the package.

You can build any logic to retrieve only Package Versions to specific packages (use `Package2Id` to filter for that) or only the latest version of a given `MajorVersion`. You can also use this to extract / solve dependencies.

Resources:

- [Tooling API Documentation: Package2Version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_package2version.htm)
- [SFDX Documentation: Extract Package Dependencies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_extract_dependency_info.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script using JQ.  Advantage being you can pass it write into install command.

#echo "Obtaining Latest Package Version"
resampleDevpackageVersion=$(sfdx  force:package:version:list  -p 0Ho3i00000000FQCAY --json | jq '.result[-1].SubscriberPackageVersionId' --raw-output)

echo "Installing Package Version:  "  $resampleDevpackageVersion
sfdx force:package:install --package $resampleDevpackageVersion -w 15

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python to obtain the highest released version, and I am incorporating additional logic to disregard patches since I only require the latest released version.

```
import subprocess
import json

def sort_packages(packages):
    return sorted(packages, key=lambda x: (int(x['MajorVersion']), int(x['MinorVersion']), int(x['PatchVersion']), int(x['BuildNumber'])))

def execute_command(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, text=True, cwd='./')

package_id = "your_package_id"
command = f"sfdx package version list -p \"{package_id}\" --released --order-by CreatedDate --concise --json"

result_json = execute_command(command)

released_versions = json.loads(result_json)['result']
released_versions = sort_packages(released_versions)

# Latest Released Version
last_package = released_versions[-1]
```